# IIS 8 error page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application, iis

Just created a new (and the first) web application for a new SharePoint environment.

When I try to access the main address it takes me to what appears to be an IIS 8 error page.

The strange thing is that the team site that I created under the main page shows up just fine.

Any ideas?[image]

Comment: @TrevorSeward this is actually an answer (or perhaps the right answer). I would suggest that you repost it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the splash page for the Default Web Site. Validate your IIS Site Bindings (these need to match the Alternate Access Mappings) and stop the Default Web Site if you're not using it. Make sure when you created your Web Application that you created a root Site Collection ("/") as Web Apps without a root SC are not supported.